# Policy for signing and encrypting

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ws-security, java-metro-framework

I need to implement a jax-ws client.

Here is what the provider docs say about security

> Currently, we use the SOAP Message Security version 1.0 specification at
>   http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf
>
> This standard uses two other from W3C norm:
>   XMLENC (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/)
>   and XMLDSIG (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/)
>
> For the signature, a “SecurityTokenReference” using a direct
>   “reference” specifying “URI” and “valueType” of X509 is mandatory. For
>   the enciphering, we recommend it too, but also we support in order of
>   preference a reference to a keyIdentifier, a X509IssuerSerial or a
>   keyName.
>
> The enciphered and signed block has to be the “body” tag.
>
> We recommend to use:      “rsa-sha1” for signature,   “rsa-1_5” for
>   encrypting key and    “tripledes-cbc” for encrypting body.

So I came up with following policy (generated from netbeans). But... it doens't look right to me. The web service isn't reachable yet, but I'm not sure that the spec versions match. I read a lot on the subject, but I'm still somewhat confused. Does this policy look ok?

```
<wsp1:Policy wsu:Id="ListeOperationsPeriodeSoapBindingSoapPolicy">
    <wsp1:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp1:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp1:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp1:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp1:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp1:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp1:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp1:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp1:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp1:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:Wss10/>
            <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <wsp1:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp1:Policy>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp1:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp1:Policy>
            </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>

        </wsp1:All>
    </wsp1:ExactlyOne>
</wsp1:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="ListeOperationsPeriodeSoapBindingSoap_perform_Input_Policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp1:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp1:X509Token sp1:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp1:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp1:X509Token>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp1:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>

</wsp:Policy>
```

EDIT:
I couldn't get it to send the expected message with wsit-yet. As an example, using Netbeans wizard, I couldn't get an encrypted header without using addressing. Is it supposed to be possible?

I hacked something with an old axis 1 class and wss4j, it works but it's ugly and I'd rather use something more future-proof.

Comment: I couldn't get it to send the expected message with wsit-yet. As an example, using Netbeans wizard, I couldn't get an encrypted header without using addressing. Is it supposed to be possible? I hacked something with an old axis 1 class and wss4j, it works but it's ugly and I'd rather use something more future-proof.

Comment: This is more of a code review question which belongs on the code review site.

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused indeed. In general you should have a single policy. In your case, you risk accepting unsecured web service calls because you have one policy defining transport binding (https), while the other is not.

Also, since you have a transport binding, that means the entire body will be encrypted by the transport protocol (https). You don't need to specify body encryption explicitly. In fact, this binding will encrypt everything except the http header.

The transport binding really is the easiest way to get secure web services. If you want total control, you have to write your own symmetric or asymetric binding depending on your needs. Asymetric is more complex because it requires a certificate on both sides, while asymetric requires only a server certificate (accepts anonymous clients). Asymetric and symmetric bindings require care. They are designed to be highly flexible and will let you design any policy, even if vulnerable to certain attacks.

When not using transport binding, then you must specify the body must be encrypted. As stated in the specs:

```
sp:EncryptedParts/sp:Body
```

Or translated into xml:

```
<sp:EncryptedParts>
  <sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
```

Similarly, if you want the body to be signed:

```
<sp:SignedParts>
  <sp:Body/>
</sp:SignedParts>
```

There are more options to specify signature/encryption order, whether to encrypt the signature or not, etc.

As the name implies, policies such as sp:EndorsingSupportingToken apply to supporting tokens. The type I'm familiar with is the username token you can include inside web services requests.

The [WS-SecurityPolicy specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/v1.3/ws-securitypolicy.html) is the single most useful doc I have read to understand policies. You should take time to read this thoroughly. It details things quite well and contains useful examples. It is good to read different versions of the docs since some aspects will be better documented in more recent versions. Note I linked v1.3.

Setup a web service client and server and write simple tests. Especially if you are new to web services.

One tool that will help you formulate policies quickly is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org). It did not support exactly what I needed but it helped me learn a couple of things. It has a great UI and it is not very hard to use.

Get some examples or build some, then deconstruct them with the help of the specification.

I have found policies to be quite complex. Be prepared to absorb a lot of concepts!

Comment: Well, I didn't have the choice. I'm the client and have nothing to say about the server, used by other clients (whatever I'd think of it). I had a wsdl without the security constraints. This wasn't negotiable.

Comment: You partners aren't very cooperative. Perhaps they're not all that interested that you call their service? If they do client auth you will never be able to call the service without the proper client certificate. If they require a username+password token, you will never be able to call the service either. Maybe they accept anonymous clients over https? Test it out. Code a simple web service using https security (ie: a single hello world function). Then code the corresponding client. Once it works, cross your fingers and try it with the 'real' service.

Comment: 'My partners' are really my client's partners, and they have a monopoly anyway so we need to call their web services because we don't have a choice and we're so englued in status-quo that it won't change anytime soon. They rule the world, you'd be surprised by what they do (their business, not the technology). Anyway, I have an ugly hack mentionned above which works in production since a few months.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try with CXF instead of WSIT? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

Comment: I could. I solved my problem with a ugly hack. The provider says it will make a decent wsdl with security constraints, maybe next year or so. When they will, I'll use wsit and it should work. In the meantime, my ugly hack works.

Comment: Did you use CXF for your ugly hack then?

Comment: No, I adapted some wss4j and metro 1 classes to work with metro, because I had a working configuration in metro / wss4j. I basically copied and changed metro classes, so there is no dependency on metro. I still believe metro is the right choice. As I had to have a deep look at wss4j, I assure you it's dirty as hell.